# How to add a contextMenu programmatically in C#(VS 2008)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I'm using VS 2008, and I would like to add a contextMenu (definitely not `ContextMenuStrip`!!) to my application. There is no contextMenu (!!) in the toolbox. So how can I add it programmatically to my code?

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use Winforms, you can initialize [`ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) class in your code. It has a 2 *[constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.contextmenu.aspx)* which you can pass `MenuItem` as a parameter.

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
```

or

```
ContextMenu cm1 = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ContextMenu context = new ContextMenu();
context.Items.Add(new MenuItem().Header = "Add To Favorites");
```

Comment: Please add a few words to your code. For users who a searching for answers is just a code not very helpful.